# KubernetesPodOperator Failing with ERROR - Pod creation failed with reason '\x1b[01mUnprocessable Entity\x1b[22m'. Failing task

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, airflow

I have installed docker and airflow in my Mac m1 chip. I have also installed minikube

when I run

```bash
eval $(minikube docker-env) and docker images

  REPOSITORY                                TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
  test-minikbs                              1.0       5ce544d80428   12 hours ago    110MB
  niketagorajanal/test-minikbs              1.0       5ce544d80428   12 hours ago    110MB
  registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver            v1.26.3   3f1ae10c5c85   3 months ago    129MB
  registry.k8s.io/kube-proxy                v1.26.3   c859f97be11a   3 months ago    61.9MB
  registry.k8s.io/kube-controller-manager   v1.26.3   3b6ac91ff8d3   3 months ago    119MB
  registry.k8s.io/kube-scheduler            v1.26.3   fa167119f9a5   3 months ago    54.9MB
  registry.k8s.io/etcd                      3.5.6-0   ef2458028240   6 months ago    181MB
  registry.k8s.io/pause                     3.9       829e9de338bd   8 months ago    514kB
  registry.k8s.io/coredns/coredns           v1.9.3    b19406328e70   12 months ago   47.7MB
  gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner   v5        ba04bb24b957   2 years ago     29MB
```

I am able to run the image also

```bash
kubectl run first-container2 --image=niketagorajanal/test-minikbs:1.0  --image-pull-policy=Never --restart=Never
pod/first-container2 created

niketa.gorajanal@RINMAC2897 ~ % kubectl logs pod/first-container2
Test Hetlo, World!
```

I am trying to access the same image via Kubernetes Pod Operator in airflow. I have made necessary changes airflow.cfg airflow.cfg configs for kubernetes

```
executor = KubernetesExecutor
in_cluster = False
config_file = /Users/niketa.gorajanal/.kube/config

[kubernetes]
dags_in_image= True
cluster_context_namespace = minikube
cluster_name = minikube
namespace = default
kube_config_path = /Users/niketa.gorajanal/.kube/config
```

```py
# Sample dag.py
with DAG('kubernetes_pod_operator_example', default_args=default_args,
schedule_interval=None) as dag:
task = KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id='pod_task',
    name='pod-task',
    namespace='default',
    in_cluster=False,
    image='niketagorajanal/test-minikbs:1.0',
    image_pull_policy='Never',
    get_logs=True
)
```

When I execute the dag in `localhost:8080` I get this below error? what am I missing?

```
INFO - Creating kubernetes pod for job is TaskInstanceKey(dag_id='kubernetes_pod_operator_example', task_id='pod_task', run_id='manual\_\_2023-06-15T06:34:20.514475+00:00', try_number=1, map_index=-1), with pod name kubernetes-pod-operator-example-pod-task-dezt70fx
/Users/niketa.gorajanal/airflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:1056 InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host '127.0.0.1'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
[2023-06-15T12:04:21.706+0530] {kubernetes_executor.py:300} ERROR - 

Exception when

attempting to create Namespaced Pod: {
"metadata": {
"annotations": {
"dag_id": "kubernetes_pod_operator_example",
"task_id": "pod_task",
"try_number": "1",
"run_id": "manual__2023-06-15T06:34:20.514475+00:00"
  },
"labels": {
"dag_id": "kubernetes_pod_operator_example",
"task_id": "pod_task",
"try_number": "1",
"kubernetes_executor": "True",
"airflow_version": "2.6.1",
"airflow-worker": "35",
"run_id": "manual__2023-06-15T063420.5144750000-ab55ac7c4"
},
"name": "kubernetes-pod-operator-example-pod-task-dezt70fx",
  "namespace": "default"
},
"spec": {
"containers": [
{
  "args": [
    "airflow",
    "tasks",
    "run",
    "kubernetes_pod_operator_example",
    "pod_task",
    "manual__2023-06-15T06:34:20.514475+00:00",
    "--local",
    "--subdir",
    "DAGS_FOLDER/minikube_dag.py"
  ],
  "env": [
    {
      "name": "AIRFLOW_IS_K8S_EXECUTOR_POD",
      "value": "True"
    }
  ],
  "name": "base"
  }
  ]
  }
}

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/niketa.gorajanal/airflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/executors/kubernetes_executor.py", line 295, in run_pod_async
resp = self.kube_client.create_namespaced_pod(
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/niketa.gorajanal/airflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py", line 7356, in create_namespaced_pod
return self.create_namespaced_pod_with_http_info(namespace, body, **kwargs) # noqa: E501
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/niketa.gorajanal/airflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py", line 7455, in create_namespaced_pod_with_http_info
return self.api_client.call_api(
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/niketa.gorajanal/airflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 348, in call_api
return self.**call_api(resource_path, method,
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/niketa.gorajanal/airflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 180, in **call_api
response_data = self.request(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/niketa.gorajanal/airflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/api_client.py", line 391, in request
return self.rest_client.POST(url,
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/niketa.gorajanal/airflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 275, in POST
return self.request("POST", url,
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/Users/niketa.gorajanal/airflow-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kubernetes/client/rest.py", line 234, in request
    raise ApiException(http_resp=r)
kubernetes.client.exceptions.ApiException: (422)
Reason: Unprocessable Entity
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Audit-Id': '9bc1aca9-2d4c-4426-abca-955189290af2', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Flowschema-Uid': '67d45002-c8d3-49a5-89e1-797e7fe490c5', 'X-Kubernetes-Pf-Prioritylevel-Uid': 'c99bb268-2652-456e-a53d-e08c433c9188', 'Date': 'Thu, 15 Jun 2023 06:34:21 GMT', 'Content-Length': '411'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Pod \"kubernetes-pod-operator-example-pod-task-dezt70fx\" is invalid: spec.containers[0].image: Required value","reason":"Invalid","details":{"name":"kubernetes-pod-operator-example-pod-task-dezt70fx","kind":"Pod","causes":[{"reason":"FieldValueRequired","message":"Required value","field":"spec.containers[0].image"}]},"code":422}

[2023-06-15T12:04:21.719+0530] {kubernetes_executor.py:718} ERROR - Pod creation failed with reason '\x1b[01mUnprocessable Entity\x1b[22m'. Failing task
```